# How to create a simple ASP website that pulls a single line from DB?

Tags: iis

I've been tasked with creating an ASP website that plugs into a db to display "Hello, World!" on the site. I've not touched either for years and no idea where to start. How would I go about creating a DB that just has this value and how to go about creating the actual site?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a quick research I've done
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ea3ed6/showing-some-data-in-Asp-Net-from-sql-server-database-using/

Just a suggestion as I think your question could be closed for lack of context: You should always include informations about what you did before asking your question, what was the outcome and anything useful.

This way, I'm sure that your stackoverflow endavors will be sucessfull

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an asp.net website, then there is a localdb tool in the vs tool, which can easily create a database and build a link with your project. This is its usage tutorial: [Create a database and add tables in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2019).

When you have tested the function of your website locally, you can publish your website through IIS. Here is the reference: [Configure the website in IIS](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#configure-the-website-in-iis).